# How do I process PHP generated content with Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, css

I Have a PHP script that generates a list element for every entry in a MySQL database. I am trying to use the jquery :odd selector on these list elements to change the background color of every other list element. It thus far hasn't worked and i think that the JS is either running before the PHP parses or some other scenario I am not aware of is causing the JS to not execute the manipulation I am trying to achieve.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
$("li:odd").css("background-color", "#000");
}

</script>
<ul id="datalist">

<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
{ 
echo "<li><br/>".$row['FName']." ".$row['LName']."<br/> Phone: ".$row['PHON']."<br/>          Workstation: ".$row['EQUIP']."<br/></li>";
} 
?>


</ul>
```

Note: This isnt the entire page just the relevant code to my question.

Comment: Whether the markup was generated using PHP or not is meaningless in this context: What counts is the resulting HTML. You need to look at that to see what goes wrong.

Comment: You should use margins instead of `<br/>` tags.

Comment: Why don't you use PHP to alternate the color?  It doesn't really make sense to use Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed a `)` at the end of your Javascript (to close the `$(document).ready(` call)

Comment: And there it is... the simples answer is usually the correct one, just needed a new set of eyes. Thank you much for answering my first question here!